# Automated labelling and references in enumerate list

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering, automation, autoref, labelling

I am preparing a syllabus book containing a number of courses. For each course, I have an enumerated list of course objectives. Then I have units/modules under the course that addresses those objectives. I want to automate this referencing process. So far, I have created the followings:

1. A code unique for each course: `\def\ccode{H11}`
2. An `enumerate` list for the course objectives:

```
\newlist{obj}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[obj,1]{itemsep=0pt,
    label=\fbox{\ccode-CO\arabic*},
    align=left, 
    labelindent=0pt,
    ref=\ccode-CO\arabic*
}
```

3. A counter for `\label` purpose:

```
\newcounter{ocount}
\newcommand\objectno{\refstepcounter{ocount}\arabic{ocount}}
\preto\enumerate{\setcounter{ocount}{0}}
```

4. And finally, I call the `label`s as arguments inside the following table:

```
\newcommand{\usummary}[4]{%
    \begingroup%
    \def\arraystretch{1.3}%
    \begin{longtable}{|P @{\hspace{0.005\linewidth}} |Q|}%
        \hline%
        \textbf{Unit:} #1   &   \textbf{\small Objectives mapped:} \ref{#3}\\
        \hline
        \textbf{Credits:} #2    &   \textbf{\small RBT levels achieved:} #4\\
        \hline%
    \end{longtable}%
    \endgroup%
}
```

However, the final product fails to compile with following message: `Missing \endcsname inserted. \item \label{\ccode\objectno}`. Please help. Below is a full MWE:

```
\documentclass[a5paper, twoside]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%
\usepackage{longtable, array, etoolbox}
%
\newcolumntype{P}{%
    >{%
        \raggedright
        \let\newline\\%
        \arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}%
    }%
    p{0.16\linewidth}%
}
\newcolumntype{Q}{%
    >{%
        \raggedright
        \let\newline\\%
        \arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}%
    }%
    p{0.78\linewidth}%
}
%
\newcommand{\usummary}[4]{%
    \begingroup%
    \def\arraystretch{1.3}%
    \begin{longtable}{|P @{\hspace{0.005\linewidth}} |Q|}%
        \hline%
        \textbf{Unit:} #1   &   \textbf{\small Objectives mapped:} \ref{#3}\\
        \hline
        \textbf{Credits:} #2    &   \textbf{\small RBT levels achieved:} #4\\
        \hline%
    \end{longtable}%
    \endgroup%
}
%
\def\ccode{H11}

%
\newlist{obj}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[obj,1]{itemsep=0pt,
    label=\fbox{\ccode-CO\arabic*},
    align=left, 
    labelindent=0pt,
    ref=\ccode-CO\arabic*
}
%
\newcounter{ocount}
\newcommand\objectno{\refstepcounter{ocount}\arabic{ocount}}
\preto\enumerate{\setcounter{ocount}{0}}
%

%
%
\begin{document}
%
\subsubsection{Objectives}
%
    The students will be able to
    \begin{obj}
        \item \label{\ccode\objectno}
        Remember the important inequalities.
        \item \label{\ccode\objectno}
        Apply the appropriate inequality for specific problems.
        \item \label{\ccode\objectno}
                Understand the fundamental properties of polynomials, including their degree, leading coefficient, and the relationship between roots and coefficients.
        \item \label{\ccode\objectno}
                Apply transformation techniques to manipulate equations, including the ability to shift and reflect graphs of polynomial functions.
        \item \label{\ccode\objectno}
                Solve cubic and biquadratic equations using appropriate methods, such as Cardan’s method and Ferrari’s method.
        \item \label{\ccode\objectno}
                Analyse and solve reciprocal and binomial equations, demonstrating proficiency in identifying and manipulating these specific equation types.
        \item \label{\ccode\objectno}
                Utilise knowledge of symmetric functions of roots to determine relationships and patterns among the roots of polynomial equations.
        \item \label{\ccode\objectno}
                Apply strategies to determine the location of roots, including the use of intermediate value theorem, Descartes' rule of signs, graphical methods and Strum's function.
        \item \label{\ccode\objectno}
                Understand basic structure of Argand plane and perform algebra thereat.
        \item \label{\ccode\objectno}
                Develop a solid understanding of geometric principles and terminology, laying the groundwork for further exploration in advanced mathematics and related fields.
        \item \label{\ccode\objectno}
                Examine essential geometric objects, including pairs of straight lines, circles, and conic sections. They will learn to analyse and manipulate these objects, investigating their properties, equations, and relationships.
        \item \label{\ccode\objectno}
                Analyse geometric objects, employ coordinate systems, derive equations, and apply geometric concepts to solve problems.
    \end{obj}
%
\subsubsection{Content}
%
    \usummary{1}{1}{\ref{\ccode1,\ccode2}}{Remembering, Understanding, Applying}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't see why you are using the LaTeX cross-referencing for this at all. If you change the ordering of items inside `\begin{obj}... \end{obj}`, the `\label`s also change because they are tied to the counter, which means that you will have to manually edit the subsequent table by hand. All this is to say: you don't really gain anything using the label/ref compared to just hardcoding those references directly. Your question therefore sounds a lot like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) to me.

Comment: I think if you explain what your code is trying to solve (fundamentally why you are using the cross referencing this way) there may be much easier solutions to your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `\objectno` is not expandable.  So, if you do it in another way you can get what you are looking for.

The `enumitem` list already have the counter on it.  So you can take advantage of it and use `\the<ListName><level>` macro.  In your case `\theobji`.  If you put this in a macro, lets say

```
\newcommand\alabel{\label{\theobji}}
```

you can have more flexibility when redefining it.  Due to the re-definition of the list, the label is stored with an extra pair of brackets (I don't know why).  So, you need to refer to it with these extra brackets as well.  That is why you see `\ref{{\ccode-CO1}}` instead.  Note that the labels are tied to the definition of the reference in the list creation (`ref={\ccode-CO\arabic*}`).

## Code

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}

\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{longtable, array}

\newcolumntype{P}{%
  >{%
    \raggedright
    \let\newline\\%
    \arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}%
  }%
  p{0.16\linewidth}%
}
\newcolumntype{Q}{%
  >{%
    \raggedright
    \let\newline\\%
    \arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}%
  }%
  p{0.78\linewidth}%
}
%
\newcommand{\usummary}[4]{%
  \begingroup%
  \def\arraystretch{1.3}%
  \begin{longtable}{|P @{\hspace{0.005\linewidth}} |Q|}%
    \hline%
    \textbf{Unit:} #1   &   \textbf{\small Objectives mapped:} \ref{#3}\\
    \hline
    \textbf{Credits:} #2    &   \textbf{\small RBT levels achieved:} #4\\
    \hline%
  \end{longtable}%
  \endgroup%
}

\def\ccode{H11}

\newlist{obj}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[obj,1]{
  itemsep=0pt,
  label=\fbox{\ccode-CO\arabic*},
  align=left, 
  labelindent=0pt,
  ref={\ccode-CO\arabic*},
}

\newcommand\alabel{\label{\theobji}}


\begin{document}
  \section{Objectives}
  
  The students will be able to
  \begin{obj}
    \item \alabel
    Remember the important inequalities.
    \item \alabel
    Apply the appropriate inequality for specific problems.
    \item \alabel
    Understand the fundamental properties of polynomials, including their degree, leading coefficient, and the relationship between roots and coefficients.
  \end{obj}
  
  \section{Content}
  
  \usummary{1}{1}{{\ccode-CO1}}{Remembering, Understanding, Applying}
 
\end{document}
```

[image]

## List of references (addition)

`cleveref` requires to redefine a name for the counter (I left it empty with `\crefname{obji}{}{}`), and doesn't work with the expansion from the reference in `enumitem`.

In this version you need to define the pattern using the number form of the counter `\arabic{obji}`.  This also solves the issue of the double bracket.  Note that you don't require to have a different pattern (`l-\ccode-CO\arabic{obji}`) w.r.t. the list, but it may help to differentiate between the examples.

The code with the example is below.

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}

\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{longtable, array}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\newcolumntype{P}{%
  >{%
    \raggedright
    \let\newline\\%
    \arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}%
  }%
  p{0.16\linewidth}%
}
\newcolumntype{Q}{%
  >{%
    \raggedright
    \let\newline\\%
    \arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}%
  }%
  p{0.78\linewidth}%
}
%
\newcommand{\usummary}[4]{%
  \begingroup%
  \def\arraystretch{1.3}%
  \begin{longtable}{|P @{\hspace{0.005\linewidth}} |Q|}%
    \hline%
    \textbf{Unit:} #1   &   \textbf{\small Objectives mapped:} \cref{#3}\\
    \hline
    \textbf{Credits:} #2    &   \textbf{\small RBT levels achieved:} #4\\
    \hline%
  \end{longtable}%
  \endgroup%
}

\def\ccode{H11}

\newlist{obj}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[obj,1]{
  itemsep=0pt,
  label=\fbox{\ccode-CO\arabic*},
  align=left, 
  labelindent=0pt,
  ref={\ccode-CO\arabic*},
}
% empty names
\crefname{obji}{}{}

\newcommand\alabel{\label{l-\ccode-CO\arabic{obji}}}


\begin{document}
  \section{Objectives}
  
  The students will be able to
  \begin{obj}
    \item \alabel
    Remember the important inequalities.
    \item \alabel
    Apply the appropriate inequality for specific problems.
    \item \alabel
    Understand the fundamental properties of polynomials, including their degree, leading coefficient, and the relationship between roots and coefficients.
  \end{obj}
  
  \section{Content}
  
  \usummary{1}{1}{l-\ccode-CO1,l-\ccode-CO2}{Remembering, Understanding, Applying}
  
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, I need to have multiple references in the third argument in `\usummary{1}{1}{{\ccode-CO1}}{Remembering, Understanding, Applying}`. I understand that `\ref` cannot pull that off, so I tried your code with `\cref` from `cleveref` package as well. No luck so far.

Comment: That is a different problem, but you can work it by redefining the labels that you are using.  See the update.

Comment: Ah! Thank you so much.